# Does this app use the Advertising Identifier (IDFA)? when using Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, app-store-connect, idfa

When i am about to review my iOS app I get this question asked. And the simple answer is "NO".

I have searched these forums but only found what i think is people using enhanced analytics framework as adSupport and such.

I use both Crashlytics and Analytics framework from Firebase. And in there i know there is code for using IDFA. Though from my understanding it is only ever used if i also use the AdSupport.framework. And i do not use it or ads in any other way.

I do use push notifications using firebase push api getting pushTokens from phone ids. But i do not think that is anything using IDFA...

What is the correct answer to this question. And if Yes. there are 3 more options. Here is the full message if "YES" is checked

Does this app use the Advertising Identifier (IDFA)?
The Advertising Identifier (IDFA) is a unique ID for each iOS device and is the only way to offer targeted ads. Users can choose to limit ad targeting on their iOS device.

If your app is using the Advertising Identifier, check your code—including any third-party code—before you submit it to make sure that your app uses the Advertising Identifier only for the purposes listed below and respects the Limit Ad Tracking setting. If you include third-party code in your app, you are responsible for the behavior of such code, so be sure to check with your third-party provider to confirm compliance with the usage limitations of the Advertising Identifier and the Limit Ad Tracking setting.

This app uses the Advertising Identifier to (select all that apply):

- Serve advertisements within the app
- Attribute this app installation to a previously served advertisement
- Attribute an action taken within this app to a previously served
  advertisement

Ensure that you select the correct answer for Advertising Identifier (IDFA) usage. If your app does contain the IDFA and you select No, the binary will be permanently rejected and you will have to submit a different binary.

Thanks in adv.

Comment: I found [this link, in github/firebase](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/266). I will encounter this problem soon.... Oops.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you don't include the AdSupport.framework in your project you don't need to worry about IDFA. The FirebaseAnalytics SDK willuse the ***advertisingIdentifier*** if the AdSupport.framework is linked into your app.

You can simply select No.

or

You can select Yes and

Serve advertisements within the app - NO

Attribute this app installation to a previously served advertisement - NO

Attribute an action taken within this app to a previously served advertisement - YES.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I got accepted answering NO on using the identifier.

Comment: What if I use GoogleMobileAds? Should I select YES or NO?

Comment: Where is this setting located in App Store Connect?